# How to check that package is not present on server in SaltStack state file?

Tags: salt-stack, aerospike

I am trying to automate an Aerospike database installation using saltstack version 2015.5.2 on an Ubuntu machine.

The following is the process of manual installation that I want to automate. (I'll only mention the key steps to keep it simple)

1. Download Aerospike

   `wget -O aerospike.tgz
   http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12`
2. extract the contents of the package

   `tar -xvf aerospike.tgz`
3. Install Aerospike Server & Tools

   `cd aerospike-server-community-3.5.15-ubuntu12.04
   ./asinstall`
4. Start Aerospike

   `/etc/init.d/aerospike start`

Step 3 performs the actual installation which includes installation of 2 packages: **aerospike-server-community** and **aerospike-tools**.

Now in the saltstack state file I want to check if both the packages are already present on server, and in that case do not execute the `./asinstall` command in step 3.

How can I involve that condition in my automated process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read [requisites in salt](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) before going on because you can find many interesting things there.

Furthermore,what you really need, in my opinion is: `UNLESS`, because if you already have these packages on your system they should not be installed. Unless can be used together with the `pkg` keyword, but for you the `rpm -q package_name` might work just as well.

It should look something like this:

```
start_process:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'write here your command'
    - unless:
      - rpm -q package1,package2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide a small comment to the answer, but my reputation does not allow me, so I apologize in advance for this.

This line:

```
- rpm -q package1,package2
```

Should actually be:

```
- rpm -q package1 package2
```